# IE scales background-image on DOM ready

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

On this project

http://jackson.collegeman.net

In IE 7 on WinXP and IE 8 on Vista, when the page loads, the background image behind my nav bar buttons scales to fit the anchor tags it's set on.

The background-image is a composite of all the buttons for the navigation bar, containing both normal and hover states. For some reason, in IE, when the DOM finishes loading, the image is scaled to fit inside each of the buttons, instead of remaining a fixed size.

Why?

Comment: @Jonathan Don't down-vote the question or anything...

Comment: The background-image is a composite of all the buttons for the navigation bar, containing both normal and hover states.  For some reason, in IE, when the DOM finishes loading, the image is scaled to fit inside each of the buttons, instead of remaining a fixed size.

Answer (score 0):

It was a bad PNG-fix script.

The one that is up there now works, if you want to grab it for yourself.